# Feasibility of NNs in solving NP-hard problems

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, algorithm

Can neural networks be used to solve NP-hard problems? I'm assuming they learn to approximate a polynomial function and hence cannot solve NP-hard unless P=NP.

In case they aren't, what are the general methods that are followed to approach these problems?

Comment: There are a lot of NP-hard problems that become P if you restrict them to some subset of inputs. And there are lot of NP-hard problems for which there exist polynomial approximate algorithms. Furthermore, you seem to have some confusion about what it is that is polynomial in a P problem and what it is that is not polynomial in a NP-hard problem.

Comment: Also, neural networks can learn to approximate a lot of different functions, not just polynomial functions. If neural networks could only approximate polynomial functions, we'd probably use neural networks a lot less and linear regression a lot more. Indeed, finding a best approximating polynomial can be done with a simple linear regression.